# Why Date.js when I'm usin setTime() set time with specific time zone

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

How can I set time without time zone?

```js
let msDate = moment(element?.value.substring(15), "MMM DD, YYYY (HH:mm:ss) ZZ").valueOf();
let date = new Date()
date.setTime(msDate)
element.value = date;
```

I use this code to set time from parsed string, but actually I get this:

```
Wed Oct 19 2022 07:00:00 GMT+0200 (за центральноєвропейським літнім часом)
```

And all that I want its get the `Date` object with "GMT+0000"

How I can do this?

Comment: So you want the UTC time? What is the `value` coming from the `element`?

Comment: Tradable After Oct 19, 2022 (7:00:00) GMT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `utc()` before calling `format()` to tell Moment that you want a UTC date.

```js
const defaultOptions = {
  isUTC: false,
  inputFormat: 'MMM DD, YYYY (HH:mm:ss) ZZ',
  outputFormat: 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ',
  pattern: /\w{3}\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}\s\(\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\)\s\w+/
};

const extractDate = (str, options) => {
  const opts = { ...defaultOptions, ...options };
  const match = str.match(opts.pattern);
  if (!match) return null;
  const [extracted] = match;
  const date = moment.utc(extracted, opts.inputFormat);
  return (!opts.isUTC ? date.local() : date).format(opts.outputFormat);
}

const inputString = "Tradable After Oct 19, 2022 (7:00:00) GMT";

// Local: Wed Oct 19 2022 03:00:00 GMT-0400
console.log('Local:', extractDate(inputString));

// UTC: Wed Oct 19 2022 07:00:00 GMT+0000
console.log('UTC:', extractDate(inputString, { isUTC: true }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But I still get Date object with time GMT+0200 when I use utc() and get GMT+0000 I get 5:00:00 instead of 7:00:00

Comment: I need Wed Oct 19 2022 07:00:00 GMT+0000

Comment: So the thing is that i get time with GMT+0000 and after I parsed this time i get GMT+0200. So in my new time object I have 2 hours less.

Comment: The problem inside Date object, ctor using locale time zone.

Comment: @Illia I updated my response. I parsed the date as a UTC time string and display LOCAL if UTC is false in the config. It appears that parsing does not respect the source time zone in the string.